# Wav file stop function

Tags: c++, winapi, wav

I need to implement some sounds in a project. I managed to do the play part, but I also need a function that can stop the file whenever it is needed.
I have the Stop function below, which is similar with the play function.

Any tips on why is not working, or some alternatives on how I can stop the file before it's ending.

```
LPCSTR const Sound_File_Open = "open C:/Users/uidn1646/Desktop/sound/1162.wav alias Current_Sound_Command";

void Stop()
{
    LPCSTR const Sound_Command = "stop Current_Sound_Command ";

    MCIERROR sound_file_action = mciSendString(Sound_File_Open, NULL, 0, NULL);
    if (sound_file_action == 0) {
        mciSendString(Sound_Command, NULL, 0, NULL);
        mciSendString("close Current_Sound_Command", NULL, 0, NULL);

    }
}
```

Comment: There is an extra space at the end of `"stop Current_Sound_Command "`. Results of second and third `mciSendString` invocations are not checked and error codes are not inspected.

Comment: It is not the space, same space is in the play function, but removed them both and still.. the stop function is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't seem to be a problem.

My idea is to add a judgment condition to the stop function.

By judging whether it is necessary to stop playing, if it is necessary to stop playing, press`'y'`or continue playing.

This is just a simple idea. If you have any other questions, please feel free to reply to me.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment (lib,"Winmm.lib")
using namespace std;

LPCSTR const Sound_Command = "stop Current_Sound_Command";

void stop();

int main() 
{
    LPCSTR const Sound_File_Open = "open C:\\Users\\strives\\Desktop\\Ring10.wav type waveaudio alias Current_Sound_Command";       
    mciSendString(Sound_File_Open, NULL, 0, NULL); 
    mciSendString("play Current_Sound_Command", NULL, 0,  NULL);

    //here you need stop play
    stop();                         
    system("pause");
}

void stop()
{   
    char letter_1 = {'y'};
    cout << "Do you want to stop play?" << endl;
    cout << "y or n" << endl;
    char letter = _getch();
    if (letter == letter_1)
    {
        MCIERROR sound_file_action = mciSendString(Sound_Command, NULL, 0, NULL);
    }
}
```

This is the simplest code demonstration for reference only.

**Updated:**

```
LRESULT CALLBACK ButtonProc(HWND hwndDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    TCHAR szText[40];
    HDC hdc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    RECT rect;
    switch (message)
    {

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        GetClientRect(hwndDlg, &rect);
        GetWindowText(hwndDlg, szText, sizeof(szText));
        hdc = BeginPaint(hwndDlg, &ps);
        Rectangle(hdc, rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom);
        DrawText(hdc, szText, -1, &rect,
            DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);
        return 0;
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    {
        mciSendString(L"open C:\\Users\\strives\\Desktop\\Ring10.wav type waveaudio alias Current_Sound_Command", NULL, 0, NULL);
        mciSendString(L"play Current_Sound_Command", NULL, 0, NULL);
    }
    break;
    case WM_LBUTTONUP:
    {
        mciSendString(L"stop Current_Sound_Command", NULL, 0, NULL);
    }
    break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwndDlg, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Customize the callback function of the button, set the mouse event of the button, press the button, play the file, release the button, stop playing.

Comment: i have something like this in the application.Long story short, when a button in a simulation is pressed pressed there is an event that will start the sound(call it the True side of an if statement), and when the button is released the sound should stop(the False side).This is a method that we use to test things.

Comment: @SilviuAlexandru You can customize the left mouse button event. I updated my answer.